# How do i enable pytest-odoo find my module

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, odoo, pytest

I want to run my test cases for my odoo module with pytest with

```
pytest -s name_of_module
```

To run pytest-odoo I have an the following steps

`export ODOO_RC=/Users/admin/odoo-15/lldev2.conf`
`pytest -s name_of_module --odoo-log-level=info`

But I get this error

```
ERROR swm_mst_lead_enh/tests/test_swm_mst_models.py - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'odoo.addons.swm_mst_lead_enh.common'
```

my modules path is in my config file, so I am not sure what is wrong